# Pass results from one activity to another

Tags: android

I am starting a child activity from a parent activity. I want the child activity to pass back results to parent activity under certain circumstances.

To start child activity I call...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SpeechActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, SPEECH_REQUEST);
```

Then in the child activity I add results to the intent. I think maybe I am adding results to the wrong intent..?

```
setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_SPEECH_TIMER);
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("minutes", time[0]);
i.putExtra("seconds", time[1]);
this.setIntent(i);
finish();
```

Then in the parent activtity onActivityResult method I try to access the bundle, but I always get null pointer.

```
else if(resultCode==RESULT_SPEECH_TIMER)
{
    Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
    int initMinutes=extras.getInt("minutes");
    int initSeconds=extras.getInt("seconds");
    setTimer(initMinutes,initSeconds);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set the result as below....

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("minutes", time[0]);
i.putExtra("seconds", time[1]);
setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_SPEECH_TIMER, i);
finish();
```

Comment: Can you explain why re-ordering the OP's lines solves the problem?

Comment: He did not reorder. I was getting intent from getIntent(). In this code he created a new intent and passed it to setResult().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As you think you are adding results to the incorrect intent. Because **[getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29)**

returns **the intent that started this activity.** So that intent you used parent activity to child activity. But in child activity you are adding values using putExtra() and trying at access it from parent activity. You can't access it in there now. Instead that you can create new intent in child activity and add data to it.

```
Intent i = Intent(ChildActivity.this,ParentActivity.class);
i.putExtra("minutes", time[0]);
i.putExtra("seconds", time[1]);
this.setIntent(i);
finish();
```

This can access in parent activity.